# How to set 25 items set for each in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to set 25 items set in loop. Suppose I have total 75 records in an array and now I'm going to execute a foreach loop. So I want to split each 3 parts of 25 items  because I want to execute a cron file that only allow 25 items each time, so if there are total 75 items then my cron will be run at 3 time with each items has 25.

I have used below the code but I could not set 25 items.

```
$cnt=1;
$i=1;
foreach ($getPendingData as $key => $value) {
    if($i == 25){
        echo "here";
    }
    $totalCnt = count($getPendingData);

    echo "totalCnt".$totalCnt;
    if ($cnt%6 == 0){ $cnt =1;  } // Make condition for set each port start from 1-5
    $postData[] = array('tid' => $value['tid'], 'from' => $cnt, 'to'=>'xxxxxxxx', 'sms' =>$value['message']);
    $cnt++;
    $i++;
} // End Loop

$postData = array('xxx' =>'xxx', 'xxx' =>1,'tasks' =>$postData);
```

Here execute cron file ..

Please help me how can i set 25 items in loop and call 3 times of cron file.

Comment: Have you tried `array_chunk` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `array_chunk`

```
// First transform the tasks to add the additional data you want
$cnt = count($getPendingData);
$pendingData = array_map(function($item) use ($cnt) {
    return [
        'tid' => $item['tid'],
        'from' => $cnt, 
        'to'=>'xxxxxxxx', 
        'sms' => $item['message']
    ];
}, $getPendingData);
$chunks = array_chunk($pendingData, 25);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // $chunk contains 25 items
    $postData = ['xxx' => 'xxx', 'xxx' => 1, 'tasks' => $chunk];
    // Call your script here
}
```